# Play framework 2.0 template parameters import

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following problem:

Let's say my template parameter looks something like this:

```
@(variable : really.super.extremely.long.package.name.ClassName)
```

Is there anyway to just import that Class so that I can reduce it to something like this:

```
@(variable : ClassName)
```

Answer (score 14):

I believe it would be in your project/Build.scala file.

In your main

```
      templatesImport += "really.super.exteremely.long.package.name._"
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. This is my main:

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion,appDependencies, mainlang = JAVA).settings(
templatesImport += "really.big.package.Class1"
templatesImport += "really.big.package.Class2"
)

Comment: Hmm, strange. Your syntax is correct. And feel free to use the ._ notation to import all of the classes from the package. If you are accessing the package from a .jar file be sure to have it contained in your build path, in the /lib folder which you will have to create. Other than that I'm not certain if I can offer any other potential solutions.

Comment: @gooser did you reload your project after you added the templatesImport? Because you need to execute “reload” for the changes to Build.scala to be picked up.

Comment: Just adding the line to Build.scala didn't work for me either. However it works if you add it as a setting to the project val:
`val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  .settings(templatesImport += "really.super.exteremely.long.package.name._")`

Comment: Also, note that after adding this line I don't think that Play marks the templates as modified so it doesn't rebuild them. You either need to change something in each template or `clean` from sbt.

Comment: This was originally for Play 2.0. I imagine you're using 2.1 or 2.2 at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to chime in and say that the above example by @Jeff LaJoie still works under Play 2.2.3

In your build.sbt

`templatesImport += "really.super.exteremely.long.package.name._"`

or

`templatesImport ++= Seq(
  "really.super.exteremely.long.package.name._",
  "another.really.super.exteremely.long.package.name._"
)`